# Can I anchor individual items in a YAML collection?

Tags: yaml

How can I write the Books collection so that I can anchor an individual item?  This document is invalid.

```
Books:
  - Title: The Cat in the Hat &catInTheHat
    Author: Dr. Seuss
  - Title: Harry Potter
    Author: JK Rowling
People:
  - Name: Bill
    FavoriteBook: *catInTheHat
  - Name: Edna
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes you can, but in your example you don't have an anchor, and since you have an alias without a corresponding anchor, you get an error (and you should because that is not allowed).
What you do have, is a scalar string `The Cat in the Hat &catInTheHat` that has an ampersand somewhere in the middle.
If you want to define an anchor you need to put that **before** the actual item (scalar, sequence, mapping).

If you just want to alias the scalar string `The Cat in the Hat` (which is the value for Title) for `FavoriteBook` you can do:

```
Title: &catInTheHat The Cat in the Hat 
Author: Dr. Seuss
```

With that, if after parsing you access the value for `FavoriteBook` from the first element of the sequence that is the value for the toplevel key `People` (in Python:  `data['People'][0]['FavoriteBook']`) you get the string "The Cat in the Hat".

If you want the first element of the sequence that is the values for `Books` you would have to do:

```
Books:
  - &catInTheHat 
    Title: The Cat in the Hat 
    Author: Dr. Seuss
  - Title: Harry Potter
    Author: JK Rowling
```

Then you actually get the representation of mapping (dict/hash/map depending on your programming language) from which you then directly can retrieve both title and author.
Depending on the programming language and YAML parsers you use, the parser might "resolve" the alias if it refers to an scalar (string, integer etc) or not. Dumping the data represented from the YAML source, results in losing the anchor and alias. For collections (sequences, mappings), this is more often not the case (i.e. they refer to the same collection object in memory and get written out as anchor + alias on serialisation).

Comment: Both the [reference implementation](http://ben-kiki.org/ypaste/) and [NimYAML](http://flyx.github.io/NimYAML/testing.html) preserve aliases to scalars in their web interfaces. PyYaml does swallow the reference because in Python, strings are immutable, which makes it difficult to retain the information that a string was aliased in the input. Don't know about other implementations.

Comment: @flyx thanks for the links, I had not heard about Nim before. I have worked mostly with PyYAML and the parsers (also for other languages) that are derived from it. I looked at preserving this when I did the preservation of merges in ruamel.yaml, but I would have had to wrap all scalars (not just strings), and decided to at least postpone working on that.

Comment: From my perspective, the primary problem with PyYaml is that it does not have an event stream API, which leads to other problems like missing support for complex keys. But this is the wrong place to discuss that. Have you considered dropping by in the freenode #yaml channel?

Comment: @flyx I haven't. I'll try to have a look one of these days.